# Does it make sense to engineer new variables and keep the original variables?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, feature-engineering

While doing some feature engineering on a dataset, I recently thought:

*When I create new features, should I keep the original ones?*

Let me specify my questions a little bit more and give you an example: 
Let's imagine we have a categorical variable called `payment_type` with the labels 'annual', 'monthly', 'weekly', 'never'. 
With `payment_type` let's say I wanted to create a new variable called `is_paid` which is 1 in case `payment_type` is 'annual', 'monthly' or 'weekly' and 0 if it is 'never'. In other words, if the individual pays or not.

Would it make sense to keep both variables? 
Meaning is it likely to improve the quality of the model?

My first thought was that they would be very likely to be highly correlated which would make them redundant or could lead to multicollinearity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be cases where you need to remove the old features, but it's not necessary. For example, in regression analysis, it's quite typical to keep both $x$ and $x^2$, where the latter is a transformation of the former. In your case, depending on the problem or data, a monthly, annually or weekly payment schedule can be a very useful feature and represent users with different characteristics. So, I don't think the original feature is redundant. But, if you for example one-hot encode these features, you'll have `is_paid = 1-never` which is quite redundant, and can cause multicollinearity problems in some algorithms (e.g. linear regression).

Comment: I think many experienced readers will be surprised at this answer, because it's relatively rare to retain all versions of a feature that is "engineered."  The whole point of engineering is to create useful features out of features that might be useless or inappropriate for the model.

Comment: Good point. But, it's also a common practice to select hopefully useful features via various downstream methods among the set of all features (new and old) because the engineered features are unfortunately not guaranteed to perform better than the old ones.